# How to test statistical probability that two distributions of boolean values are different

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

I'm looking for the name of a statistical test or method to compute the statistical probability that H0 : two distributions of boolean variables are the same.

In an example, let's say i have a weighted coin that have a bias. If you throw it, you have either heads (1) or tails (0) and you have with this coin 20% chance to get heads, and 80 to get tails.
It exists other coins that can yields for example 40% chance heads and 60% chance tails, or whatever.

I would like to know a method or test to calculate the probability that i'd be wrong saying that an identically biased coin have been used to get two distributions of flip trials results.

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100668/paired-test-for-comparing-boolean-data) test but for paired data. Or in my case, i'd like to be able to test a distribution of 1000 coin flips with one coin to a distribution of 150 coin flips for the other, if i follow my example.

I looked aroung but i may lack some vocabulary to found what i'm looking for. And i lack knowledge on how to calculate weighted probabilities of probabilities, sadly...

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Google "test of proportions."  There's plenty about this [here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+of+proportions+two-sample+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2).

Comment: @whuber Thanks ! And also for the link to "Significance test for two groups with dichotomous variable". Seems to contain more than every info i need with an anwsome answer.